# An Organic Polymer that can be hardened into a glass like substance?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, chemistry, biochemistry

Continuation question from this: [The Biology behind a slime that uses hydrofluoric acid to disable and digest prey.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121896/the-biology-behind-a-slime-that-uses-hydrofluoric-acid-to-disable-and-digest-pre)

I've designed a slime that has a bunch of acids and non reactive polymers in its make up, and I was wondering if there would be a way to harden the polymers it produces into a faux glass? I know shellac is a similar material, but a stronger and possibly clearer substance would be best. Is it possible for a polymer with such an effect to exist in a highly acidic creature? (P.S. Anything with calcium would certainly be destroyed by the acid, so if calcium is required that rules it out.)

Comment: Perhaps try to explain what properties of glas you want to keep and which ones you don't care about. Btw, why do you want it to be "organic"? As is, I think this belongs on the chemistry SE. There is no world building context established at all

Comment: What have polycarbonate or polymethilmethacrylate that doesn't work for you?

Comment: When you say "a bunch acids" could you be more specific? a low concentration of formic acid will have a very different answer from a high concentration of sulphuric. and when you say polymer are you specifically referring to organic polymers I.E. proteins or do anypolymers work I.E. polyalkenes

Comment: @Raditz_35 I mean as in window glass, I was hoping that slime skin could be hunted and cured in order to produce panes of 'glass' for windows.

Comment: @Ummdustry Certainly hydrofluoric acid, but possibly digestive acids given off by microbes and or byproducts of microbe digestion. And by polymers I mean any polymer that could be made by an organism, or a colony of amino producing organisms.

Comment: @AlexP Could plexiglass be created by heating and or curing the base materials inside a living creature? Because not that many animals that I know of have plexiglass windows pre installed.

Comment: Why not? The synthesis of polymethylmethacrylate does not involve outrageus temperatures or pressures. As a bonus, the most widely used synthesis process of the monomer methyl methacrylate starts with acetone and hydrogen cyanide (both are unexceptional metabolic products).

Comment: @AlexP Thank you, that helps a lot. My chemistry knowledge is quite limited.

Comment: @AlexP Those comments should be an answer, please.

Comment: @Raditz_35, [tag:creature-design] has been a long-standing worldbuilding feature.  C.F. the entire [anatomically correct series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series).

Comment: In principal, I think this question is on topic, but I don't think enough information is given to formulate an answer. But, I'm not a chemistry expert, so I'll leave it to someone with more chemistry knowledge to cast a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have your slime make use of Chitin:

- [Chitin - Encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopedia.com/science-and-technology/biochemistry/biochemistry/chitin)
- [Chitin - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin)

This document: [Chitin and Chitosan](https://www.docdroid.net/3apDKoV/3-struszczyk.pdf)

gives a strong indication that at least some forms of Chitin are resistant to the acids you are wanting to use. Interestingly the same document indicates it is susceptible to some organic acids such as citric acid...

OK - After some pointers in comments from the OP about what the desired actual outcome is:

This article here:
[Extremely Strong and Transparent Chitin Films](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/adfm.201701100)

Indicates there is a valid method to make use of chitin in the way you want.  Unfortunately the detail is locked away behind a paywall... This could be a method of harvesting Chitin in large quantities from the slime - and manufacturing thin panes of "glass".

As an alternative, I suggest that having your slime develop a thin flat transparent Chitin in response to particular stimulae may give you the outcome you are looking for.

So have your farmer discover that if he traps the slime in a space with a flat surface, and "feeds" it corn husks and cobs, it will develop a hard (ish) skin that remains when he starves the slime. After cleaning the dead slime away, he is left with a semi transparent sheet.  Possibly he would also need to shock it with electricity, to stimulate the growth of the "armour".  Or maybe subject it to poking with sticks?  (So some kind of device that lowers a large tray of densely set bristles)

Different feed-stocks may produce different clarity of the resulting "glass"

Comment: While I thank you for the contribution, I actually want to create a reason to harvest slimes. I was looking for an alternative to glass that could be hardened from one of the liquids slimes produce, which will probably end up being acrylic. That way it can be hardened into sheets, allowing for a high class sheet of glass that would be worth a lot to nobles.

Comment: Also, the calcium in hardened chitin would be eaten by the hydrofloric acid in the slimes almost instantly.

Comment: I didn't realise you were looking to harvest the slime for making glass - I thought you were trying to have the slime produce some kind of armour...  I'll have a bit of a think - and maybe edit something else in  BUT BTW Chitin itself is not neccesarily made of Calcium - some crustaceans have Calcium as a component of their exoskeletan.  The Chitin itself is a quite different compund From the first link I gave:- "it is a polysaccharide , a type of carbohydrate that has a basic structure of a repeating chain of sugar molecules. Chitin is analogous in structure to cellulose"

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that afterwords. I read it wrong the first time and accidentally thought it said it used calcium, not that it could incorporate it. However the chitosan link doesn't work for me. Perhaps because it's a pdf?

Comment: No Worries.   The link seems not to work for me either now.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: OK - link fixed (found a PDF site to host it on...)

Comment: Oh, that was a great resource. Thank you.

Comment: Considering slimes contain super deadly hydroflouric acid which can dissolve metals, rock, glass, and humans, I don't think many would try to farm them. They're extremely hard to kill as well, since they're a colonial organism that survives if any are left alive, and since burning them releases clouds of the acid which is also deadly you can't really do that either.  I guess you could bury them but that defeats the purpose. Anyways, even just moving them is dangerous, I can't imagine a farmer would risk his life by messing with them. Probably researchers trying to kill them discovers it.